# post method data is not sending correctly in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Hi I want to send data to server using post method but not using ajax I am sending data like this:

```
function handleLogin()
{

var form = $("#loginForm");    
 var u = $("#username", form).val();
var p = $("#password", form).val();
var d = $("#dob", form).val();

if(u != '' && p!= '')
{

    var finalStr = u+encodeURIComponent("|^")+p+encodeURIComponent("|^")+encodeURIComponent("|^")+"X"+encodeURIComponent("|^")+d+encodeURIComponent("|^")+"1.0"+encodeURIComponent("|^|$");
    var encodedURL = encodeURI(intranetUrl+"customer/Ri_logon5.asp?requestString=");
    var parameters =  decodeURIComponent(finalStr);
    post_to_url(encodedURL,parameters);      

}


else
{

    alert("You must enter a username and password", function() {});
    $("#submitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
}


}
```

and my post_to_url function is as:

```
function post_to_url(url, params) {
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.action = url;
form.method = 'POST';

for (var i in params)
{
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(i))
    {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'hidden';
        input.name = i;
        input.value = params[i];
        form.appendChild(input);                      
    }
}

 form.submit();
}
```

But from server I got response not an object which comes when u pass wrong parameter. But when I pass same parameter with ajax ten it works perfectly. why is it so?

my url format is:http://myDomain/Ri_logon5.asp?requestString=

and parameter format is like this:manish|^info1234|^|^X|^11111985|^1.0|^|$

If I enter url and pass parameter in rest client then it give proper response.

Comment: I have one string name as parameters in above code. I just want to send this string using post method. If I send this string in REST Client tool as body then REST Client give me proper result. I think errror is because of that name value pair.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you want to use POST instead of GET, you should change youre code from passing multiple post values. What you want is to only post requestString. Also you should change the url to: myDomain/Ri_logon5.asp

```
function post_to_url(url, params) {
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.action = url;
form.method = 'POST';

// Change this to fetch the arguments and build the string accordingly
var postString = 'manish|^info1234|^|^X|^11111985|^1.0|^|$'; 

var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'hidden';
input.name = 'requestString';
input.value = postString
form.appendChild(input);  

 form.submit();
}
```

Comment: No I want to send data using post. When I test it on REST Client then also I select method as post

Comment: Could you then give us what is posted using your code? 

I see that you are using input.name = i;
But remember that i is just an integer, and on the server side you are getting the data by using $_POST["NAME-VALUE-FROM-POSTED-DATA"]

Comment: I want to post this string using post=>   manish|^info1234|^|^X|^11111985|^1.0|^|$

Comment: If I use URL as http://myDomain/Ri_logon5.asp?requestString=  and parameter as  manish|^info1234|^|^X|^11111985|^1.0|^|$  and select method type as Post in REST Client then it gives me proper output.

Comment: Thanks for response. But now server getting value as:requestString=manish%7C%5Einfo1234%7C%5EX%.... means speacial characters are going in other format

Comment: Try using urldecode ( string $str ) on the response: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: Hi Sindre I think we dont have to pass requestString in body. Because if on Rest client if I use url as http://10.16.240.12/ria/customer/Ri_logon5.asp? and parameter in body as requestString=manish|^info1234|^|^X|^11111985|^1.0|^|$ then not get desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I had used following mwthod in ajax which works fine:

```
$.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                            url: clientDetailURL,
                            data: finalclientDetailParam
                          }).done(function( msg1 )
                          {
                                      var clientDetailResponse = msg1;
                                      console.log("Client detail response is:"+clientDetailResponse);


                          });
```

and here clientDetailURL is:http://myDomain/Ri_logon5.asp?requestString=
and finalClientDetailParam are: manish|^info1234|^|^X|^11111985|^1.0|^|$

and for this ajax it works fine but same not for POST method without ajax. It is totally confusing.